# Spring Boot can't find classpath property from dependency module

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I currently have a Spring Boot application with a dependency to a Java module. This Java module has some classpath properties. When I @Autowired a bean from the Java module in my Spring Boot application and define this bean with a @Bean annotation and then run the Spring Boot application it will throw errors.

Error thrown:

```
2017-02-07 12:16:03.188  WARN 17620 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClassPathProperty' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'myClassPathProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

Property defined in Java Module

```
src/main/resources/myproject-context.xml
<util:properties id="myClassPathProperties" location="classpath:myproject.properties" />
```

Property usage in Java Module

```
@Value("#{myClassPathProperties['property.x']}")
public void setClassPathProperty(String x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

Bean definition in Spring Boot application

```
@Bean (name = "mailSubscriptionDao")
public MyService getMyService() {
    return new MyServiceImpl();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a ger propertie in the setClassPathProperty

Comment: are you sure that `src/main/resources/myproject-context.xml`is loaded?

Comment: Only including a dependency and creating an instance of a class of that module will not load the xml file. You will have to tell spring boot to load the xml file.

Comment: @Gatusko You mean a get property? Because I do have a getClassPathProperty() variant

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the whole properties object injected

```
@Autowired    
Properties myClassPathProperties;
```

If this works, you know you have loaded myproject-context.xml correctly.
Than you can also have a look with the debugger, whether a property with name 'property.x' exists or not.